# Optimising Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, optimization

I have the following code

```
def calculate_metrics
    reach_values = {}
    reach_values['reach_change_value'] = 0
    reach_values['reach_change_type'] = 'nochange'

    if find_yesterdays_metrics
      change = (get_influencer_metrics["total_count"]).to_i - find_yesterdays_metrics.reach_count
      reach_values['reach_change_value'] = change.abs

      case
        when change < 0
          reach_values['reach_change_type'] = "down"
        when  change > 0
          reach_values['reach_change_type'] = "up"
      end
    end

    reach_values
  end

def set_metrics_data
    @facebook_metrics = @influencer_metrics.new(
      reach_change_value: calculate_metrics['reach_change_value'],
      reach_change_type: calculate_metrics['reach_change_type'],
      social_account: SocialAccount.friendly.find('facebook')
    )
  end
```

The `calculate_metrics` is being called twice right now and being fully processed twice. Is there any suggestions on how i can optimize the same so that i dont have to process the same data twice.

Comment: As from a quick look, in set_metrtics_data why not put the result of calculate_metrics in a tmp variable x and then ask of x : calculate_metrics[y] and x : calculate_metrics[z]?

Comment: ahh makes sense :) will try it out :)

Comment: let me know the result :)

Comment: @M.Suurland works :) is there any way i can optimize the `calculate_metrics` method further?

Comment: Was in a small meeting, let me check, what about getting ride of the case statement and use a short hand if instead (this is just syntax things not really optimisation? so change < 0 ?  reach_values['reach_change_type'] = "down" : reach_values['reach_change_type'] = "up"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `set_metrics_data` put the result of calculate_metrics in a tmp variable, lets call it `x` and then ask of `x` the type and value. Which will look like:

```
x = calculate_metrics  
reach_change_value : x['reach_change_value'] 
each_change_type : x['reach_change_type']`
```

As a result the call to calculate_metrics is only called once (and stored in a tmp variable `x`).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the M. Suurland answer like

```
x = calculate_metrics  
reach_change_value : x['reach_change_value'] 
each_change_type : x['reach_change_type']`
```

and for some optimize/syntax change calculate_metrics you can use like this

```
def calculate_metrics
    reach_values = {'reach_change_value': 0, 'reach_change_type': "nochange"}
    yesterday_mat = find_yesterdays_metrics
    if yesterday_mat
        change = (get_influencer_metrics["total_count"]).to_i - yesterday_mat.reach_count
        reach_values = 
            case change
            when change < 0
              {'reach_change_type': "down", 'reach_change_value': change.abs}
            when  change > 0
              {'reach_change_type': "up", 'reach_change_value': change.abs}
            else
                reach_values
            end
    end
    reach_values
end
```

Comment: Your additional suggestion does not optimize his code, you just changed the syntax. In the end the compiled code will be the same as his orginal.

Comment: Oh dear @M.Suurland I have also changed some code as well, with syntax,do not just downvote

Comment: Optimizing code or changing its syntax are two complete different things. Name this in your suggestion. The way you formulate it now ("further optimize calculate_metrics") will make him think your suggestion "runs" faster than his original which is not the case

Comment: @M.Suurland I have also changed code to not used find_yesterdays_metrics two times dear, it will call only once now

Comment: Fine, excuse me, however since we do not know the find_yesterdays_metrics method, we can only suggest this will improve his code. Besides it is off-topic.